# unable to write a test spec for a controller's method

Tags: mockito, scalatest, playframework-2.6

I am unit testing this method of my controller class. The method executes few asynchronous database queries and depending on the result, `Redirect`s the request. The success of previous database query determines if the next query needs to be done or not.

```
def verifyUser(token:String) = Action.async {
     implicit request => {
       println("verifyUser action called with token: " + token) //TODOM - add proper handling and response

       val result:Future[Result] = for{tokenOption:Option[UserToken] <- userTokenRepo.findOne(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))  //generator 1 - get token from database
                                    userOption:Option[User] <- if (tokenOption.isDefined) {println(s"received tokenOption ${tokenOption}");userRepo.findOne(tokenOption.get.userKeys)} else {Future.successful(None)} //generator2. found token, look for corresponding user to which the token belongs
                                    modifiedUser:Option[User] <- if (userOption.isDefined) {println(s"received userOption ${userOption}");confirmSignupforUser(userOption.get)} else Future.successful(None) //generator 3. found user and token. Update profile
                                    deletedToken:Option[UserTokenKey] <- if(modifiedUser.isDefined) {println(s"received modified ${modifiedUser}");userTokenRepo.delete(UserTokenKey(UUID.fromString(token)))} else Future.successful(None)
       }
         yield { //check if we have user and token and modified user here. If any is missing, return error else success
           println("db query results tokenOption: "+tokenOption+", userOption: "+userOption+" : modifiedUserOption: "+modifiedUser+", deletedToken: "+deletedToken)
           if(tokenOption.isDefined && userOption.isDefined && modifiedUser.isDefined && deletedToken.isDefined)
              Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=success")//TODOM - pick from config
           else
             if(tokenOption.isEmpty)
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
           else if(userOption.isEmpty)
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
           else if(modifiedUser.isEmpty)
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
           else //this shouldn't happen. Unexpected
             Redirect("http://localhost:9000/home"+";signup=error")//TODOM - pick from config
         }
       result.recover { case x => {
         println("Future failed in validateUserSession. Recovering. Returning Internal Server Error" + x)
        }
       }
       result //returning Future[Result]
     }
   }
```

The controller also has a method `confirmSignupforUser` which is called by `verifyUser` method in the for loop

To test the code, I have written the following spec

```
"verify token method" should {
    "work " in {
      val testEnv = new TestEnv(components.configuration)
      when(testEnv.mockUserTokenRepository.findOne(ArgumentMatchers.any[UserTokenKey])).thenReturn(
        Future{
          println(s"returning mocked token ${testEnv.userToken}")
          Some(testEnv.userToken)}
      )

      when(testEnv.mockUserRepository.findOne(ArgumentMatchers.any[UserKeys])).thenReturn(Future{
        println(s"returning mocked user ${testEnv.user}")
        Some(testEnv.user)
      })

      when(testEnv.controller.confirmSignupforUser(ArgumentMatchers.any[User])).thenReturn(
        Future{
          println(s"confirming mocked user ${testEnv.user}")
          Some(testEnv.user)
        }
      )

      when(testEnv.mockUserTokenRepository.delete(ArgumentMatchers.any[UserTokenKey])).thenReturn(
        Future{
          println(s"returning mocked token key ${testEnv.userTokenKey}")
          Some(testEnv.userTokenKey)
        }
      )


     val request = FakeRequest("POST", s"ws/users/signup/${testEnv.mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID()}")
      println("sending request", request)

    val resultFuture:Future[Result] = testEnv.controller.verifyUser(testEnv.mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID().toString()).apply(request)
      val responseBody = contentAsString(resultFuture)
      println(s"received response ${responseBody}")
      1 mustBe 1
    }
  }
```

My test is throwing a `null` pointer exception.

```
created TestEnv with configuration...

    confirming user: null
    returning mocked user User(11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111,UserProfile(Some(InternalUserProfile(LoginInfo(credentials,test@test.com),1,true,Some(PasswordInfo(someHasher,somePassword,Some(someSalt))))),ExternalUserProfile(test@test.com,ln,fn,Some(somePassword))))
    returning mocked token UserToken(11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111,11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111,UserKeys(1,test@test.com,LoginInfo(credentials,test@test.com),fn,ln),2019-03-27T17:08:43.861Z,true)

    java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at controllers.UserController.confirmSignupforUser(UserController.scala:442)
```

The piece of code which seem to cause the issue is

```
def confirmSignupforUser(user:User):Future[Option[User]] = {
    println("confirming user: "+user)
  ...
}
```

The above code is being called from my spec it seems
    when(testEnv.controller.confirmSignupforUser(ArgumentMatchers.any[User])).thenReturn(
        Future{
          println(s"confirming mocked user ${testEnv.user}")
          Some(testEnv.user)
        }
      )

I have few doubts.
question 1) I am not mocking `testEnv.controller`. Can I still use `when` in one of the methods of `testEnv.controller` (`testEnv.controller.confirmSignupforUser(ArgumentMatchers.any[User])`)?

Question 2) Am I correct that in the `for` loop, `userTokenRepo.findOne` should return mocked value `Some(testEnv.userToken)`. This should be then be used `userRepo.findOne(tokenOption.get.userKeys)` which should return mocked value `Some(testEnv.user)`. This should be used in `confirmSignupforUser(userOption.get)`? 
Question 3) Why is `confirmSignupforUser` getting a `null` value?

Answer (score 0):

my bad. I realise that I cannot use `when` and pass `controller`'s method as I am not mocking the controller. I deleted the below line as thhe test has moved forward

```
//don't need this
when(testEnv.controller.confirmSignupforUser(ArgumentMatchers.any[User])).thenReturn(
    Future{
      println(s"confirming mocked user ${testEnv.user}")
      Some(testEnv.user)
    }
  )
```